# Как в Qt использовать сохранение файлов инструментами C?

Tags: c++, qt

Пытаюсь сохранить в данные в файл. Но сохранить в директорию с русским именем у меня не получается. У меня создано две папки одна на русском "Результаты", другая на английском "DDR".
Сохранение в английскую директорию прекрасно работает, но в русскою директорию - нет .
Я сделал пару "выводов" чтобы посмотреть результат. Вот он:

> МЫ ТУТ
>
> file_name  "C:/Works/untitled16/Результаты/2016-08-30_10-54-24.txt"
>
> str  d??
>
> fname  C:/Works/untitled16/Результаты/2016-08-30_10-54-24.txt
>
> Error save Re & Im!
>
> END

Перейти к использованию Qt для работы с файлами (QFile) можно. Но я бы для начала попробовал другие методики. Ибо хотелось бы подружить СИ и Qt.

```
//проверка создания папки
if (QFile().exists(trUtf8("Результаты"))) 
{

    qDebug() << "МЫ ТУТ ";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Папочка не созданна ";
    return;
}
// тут полный путь файла , название файла
//    file_name = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "DDR" + "/" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".txt";

file_name = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + QString::fromUtf8("Результаты").toLocal8Bit().data() + "/" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".txt";
// проверка как это будет выглядеть на СИ . Результат будет при выполнении всего этого блока  (в результата последний вывод, после END) 
char str[255];
printf(str, "%s", qPrintable(file_name));
fflush(stdout);

qDebug()<< "file_name " <<file_name;
qDebug()<< "str " <<str;

if(file_name.isEmpty())
{
    qDebug() << "хренька печенька ";
    return;
}
// перевод QString в char
char fname[255];
sprintf((char*)fname,"%s",file_name.toLocal8Bit().data());


qDebug() << "fname " <<fname;


FILE *fid=0;
fid=fopen(fname, "wb");

if(fid)
{
    fwrite("привет\n", strlen("привет\n"), 1, fid);
    fclose(fid);
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error save Re & Im! " ;
}
qDebug() << "END";
```

//-------------------------------------------------------------

Я попробывал использовать _wfopen

```
// тут сохраненине файла бинарника
file_name = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "DDR" + "/" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".bin";
// file_name = QDir::current().absolutePath() + "/" + "Результаты" + "/" + QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss") + ".bin";
if(file_name.isEmpty())
{
    qDebug() << "хпреньа11 печенька ";
    return;
}

wchar_t fname[255];
swprintf(fname, L"%s",file_name.toLocal8Bit().data());


FILE *fid=0;
fid = _wfopen(fname, L"wb");// L - необходим, ибо иначе это будет строка типа char.

qDebug() << "K";
if(fid)
{
    char buffer[] = { 'w' , 't' , 'f' };
    fwrite(buffer , 1 , sizeof(buffer) , fid );
    fclose(fid);
    qDebug() << "G";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Error save Re & Im! "   ;
}
```

Результат меня сильно удивил . C директорией "Результаты" , вообще не заработал , а с директорией "DDR". Заработал, но создал в самой папке программы файл 㩃圯牯獫猯桯慲彮灷灡畫䐯剄㈯㄰ⴶ㤰ㄭ弴㔱〭ⴷ㌵戮湩 .

Подскажите как создать хотя бы на Си ++ (можно какаю ни буть библиотеку ), как сохранить в русскую директорию .

Comment: А что записано в errno после попытки открытия файла? (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cerrno/errno/) Может вам использвать _wfopen, т.к. этот метод будет работать и для японского и китайского..

Comment: printf(str, "%s", qPrintable(file_name)); - тут не sprintf() ли должен быть?

Comment: Не знаю не проверял , не критично . Наверно sprintf()